# Why do I have to download dotenv package if I can use .env file without it?

Tags: reactjs, vite, dotenv

I am working on a React project, where I have to use an API. To use environment variables, I have created a `.env` file, and it is working fine without installing the `dotenv` package.

Why do I need to install the `dotenv` package from npm? What am I missing when I am not using dotenv? Because the project is working fine without dotenv.

I'm using `npm create vite` by the way.

Comment: Did you use `create-react-app` or `create-next-app` to set up your project?

Comment: I used npm `npm create vite@latest`

Comment: Thaks for answering. Check my below answer and let me know please.

Comment: dotenv automates activating environment variables automatically when you change directories, instead of requiring manual interaction. It's not at all requires, just a convenience.

Comment: `vite` has it under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the project-creating scripts, like `create-react-app`, `create-next-app`, or the one you said you are using, `npm create vite`, handle environment variables reading for you out of the box. In the case of vite, they use `dotenv` under the hood, as they say on the [doc](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files):

> Vite uses `dotenv` to load additional environment variables from the following files in your environment directory: `.env` (loaded in all cases), `env.local` (loaded in all cases, ignored by git)...

So yeah, you don't need to install `dotenv` yourself. Just create a `.env` file, and you can use its variables in your code.

Comment: What about deployment, is dotenv only for development. Or is there any use of dotenv in deployment. By the way, thanks for answering :)

Comment: It can be used in both cases. And in both cases, when you install your project, it will be installed as part of Vite, so you don't have to do anything.